# Broken regexp replace in TeXstudio macros

Tags: texstudio

Here's a problem I've encountered when I tried make a script in TeXstudio with several replace queries. Suppose I have some text:

```
Here goes some text, more text and some more text.
```

And when I apply this macro

```
%SCRIPT
editor.replace(/\s(text)([\.,\s])/g, '\mbox{\1}\2')
```

to it, the resulting text is messed up:

[image: Here goes somembox{} morembox{}and some morembox{}]

(in a text field it looks like this)
[image: Here goes somembox{} morembox{}and some morembox{}]

In the meantime everything works fine when the same regexp is called from GUI Replace menu:

```
Here goes some \mbox{text}, more \mbox{text} and some more \mbox{text}.
```

The text in UTF-8 encoding. Is that behaviour a bug, or my script lacks something important?

Comment: maybe you have to mask the `\ ` in the replace pattern as `\\ ` (which would be very uncommon). Or it doesn't use `\1` `\2` and instead `$1` `$2` etc. check the manual for the replacement command

Comment: @musicman The problem is - numbered matches aren't even mentioned in manual:http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33 . And I've tried $1 (since these are supposed to be js-macros), but it puts '$1' literally both in macro and UI, but \1 does the substitution in UI command.

Comment: @musicman hm, changing \ to \\ seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The current TeXstudio [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html) doesn't seem to specify the usage of numbered matches in macros. But thanks to [@musicman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/46389/musicman)'s suggestion (changing single slash **\** to double slash **\\**) I was able to make the script work:

```
%SCRIPT
editor.replace(/\s(text)([\.,\s])/g, ' \\mbox{\\1}\\2')
```

The result is correct now:

```
Here goes some \mbox{text}, more \mbox{text} and some more \mbox{text}.
```